# Fastest way to solve a system of linear equations

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-algorithms

I have to solve a system of up to 10000 equations with 10000 unknowns as fast as possible (preferably within a few seconds). I know that Gaussian elimination is too slow for that, so what algorithm is suitable for this task?

All coefficients and constants are non-negative integers modulo p (where p is a prime). There is guaranteed to be only 1 solution.  I need the solution modulo p.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) of a $n \times n$ matrix can be computed in $O(M(n))$ time, where $M(n)$ is the time to multiply two $n \times n$ matrices.  Therefore, you can find a solution to a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns in $O(M(n))$ time.  For instance, [Strassen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) achieves $M(n) = O(n^{2.8})$, which is faster than Gaussian elimination.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion.

Rather than trying to implement this yourself, I would suggest using a library: e.g., a BLAS library.

Comment: Also reduce modulo p at the end of the computation.

Comment: @fade2black, actually, it's probably going to be far better to use an implementation that is designed for use with mod p arithmetic (i.e., is reducing mod p at each step, not only at the end).

Comment: In case the Wikipedia link changes, the reference given there for the $O(M(n))$ result can be found e.g. in section 28.2 of the 3rd edition of Cormen et al, _Introduction to Algorithms_. Specifically they show the "algorithmic equivalence" between matrix multiplication and matrix inversion. But presumably one can then link matrix inversion and LU decomposition.

Comment: An [even faster method](https://www.quantamagazine.org/new-algorithm-breaks-speed-limit-for-solving-linear-equations-20210308) was described in a recent paper, using a randomized algorithm to solve sparse linear systems.

Answer (score 5):

There is what you want to achieve, and there is reality, and sometimes they are in conflict. First you check if your problem is a special case that can be solved quicker, for example a sparse matrix. Then you look for faster algorithms; LU decomposition will end up a bit faster. Then you investigate what Strassen can do for you (which is not very much; it can save 1/2 the operations if you multiply the problem size by 32).

And then you use brute force. Use a multi-processor system with multiple threads. Use available vector units. Arrange your data and operations to be cache friendly. Investigate what is the fastest way to do calculations modulo p for some fixed p. And you can often save operations by not doing operations modulo p (result in the range 0 ≤ result < p) but a bit more relaxed (for example result in the range -p < result < p).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve big linear equations is to use parallelisation or somehow to distribute computations among CPUs or so.

See CUDA, OpenCL, OpenMP.

A lot of people suggests `Strassen's algorithm` but it has a very big hidden constant which makes it inefficient.

By the way: your linear equations might be very sparse(a lot of zeros), there are few very neat optimisations to solve them in parallel.

Comment: The matrix size is 10,000 by 10,000 so I assume Strassen would be able to save something. Just not very much.

Comment: @gnasher729 I've some doubts, [Alex Stapanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stepanov) in one of his lectures it is mentioned that Boing was using Strassen's algorithm for really big matrices(1Mx1M afair) and they were unhappy with performance. But I think this info is kinda outdated for modern hardware.

Answer (score 2):

In real problems when the size is large ($n>100000$) the best approach is the numerical solution of the system by an iterative method like GMRES, CG, BiCG, etc. All those algorithms depends strongly on matrix-vector products, so the complexity is as much as $O(n^2)$ which performs better than a direct solution by a LU decomposition with complexity of $O(n^3)$.

Sometimes the scale of the problem is not large enough to the proposed methods to be an improvement compared to LU decomposition, so there is a work you have to do in balance the applicability of the methods.